# Case names for locale interpretation

Tags: isabelle, isar

Some of my locals have quite a few assumptions, very much resembling inductions over data types (that’s where the assumptions come from). When interpreting such a locale, having named cases would be very handy. How do I achieve that the following works?

```
locale Foo = 
  fixes P
  assumes 0: "P 0"
  assumes Suc: "P n ⟹ P (Suc n)"

interpretation Foo "λ _ . True"
proof(default)
  case 0 show ?case..
next
  case (Suc n) show ?case ..
qed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `default` internally calls the methods `rule`, `unfold_locales` and `intro_classes`. None of these support `case` names (for `unfold_locales`, this has been discussed already on the [Isabelle mailing list in 2008](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2008-July/msg00073.html)). So there is no way to get the `case_name` system to work with `default`. That thread mentions two important points:

1. If your locale hierarchy is flat, `unfold_locales` essentially just applies the rule `Foo.intro` where `Foo` is the name of the locale. If you have a complex hierarchy of locales, it checks which interpretations are already available and combines the `.intro` rules accordingly.
2. `cases` is the canonical method to get case names.

Thus, you can get case names manually with the `case_name` attribute:

```
interpretation Foo "λ _ . True"
proof(cases rule: Foo.intro[case_names 0 Suc])
```

Of course, you can also tag a theorem with the case names if you need it multiple times:

```
lemmas Foo_intro[case_names 0 Suc] = Foo.intro
```

The problem with case name support in `unfold_locales` is that the implementation does not keep track of which subgoal comes from which locale inheritance. If you have some spare time, feel free to implement support for case names.

Comment: Thanks, especially for pointing out `Foo.intro`. I had the feeling that this was the case, but cound’t find it, because the theorem does not show up when I issue `find_theorems Foo`.

Comment: I had the same trouble and thus used the awkward auxiliary lemmas in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know methods `induct` and `case` are responsible for setting up named cases. Thus I don't see a way that `default` would do as you ask.

You could introduce a new rule like

```
lemma foo_rule [case_names 0 Suc]:
  assumes "P 0"
    and "⋀n. P n ⟹ P (Suc n)"
  shows "foo P"
  using assms by (simp add: foo_def)
```

or alternatively like

```
lemmas foo_rule [case_names 0 Suc] =
  conjI [THEN foo_def [THEN meta_eq_to_obj_eq, THEN iffD2], rule_format]
```

if you are thusly inclined. And then use

```
interpretation foo "λ_. True"
proof (induct rule: foo_rule)
```

Accidentally I found out that declaring `foo_rule [case_names 0 Suc, induct type]` allows you to omit the rule name, i.e.,

```
interpretation foo "λ_. True"
proof (induct)
```

But I could imagine that this would break existing default induct rules.